# Get request in views.py with id

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Word`. I need change method `get` in `WordView` class in `views.py` file so that it processes: `GET /words/{id}` request. Example response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "to ask out",
    "translation": "Пригласить на свидание",
    "transcription": "tuː ɑːsk aʊt",
    "example": "John has asked Mary out several times.",
}
```

My code in get method:

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
from models import Word

class WordView(View):

    def get(self, request, id):     # Maybe there shouldn't be `id` argument

        item = Word.objects.get(id=id)
        items_data = [{
            'id': item.id,
            'word': item.word,
            'transcription': item.transcription,
            'translation': item.translation,
            'example': item.example,
        }]

        return JsonResponse(items_data[0])
```

Question 1: how I need change `ulrs.py` (for request `/words/{id}`)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('words/{id}', WordView.as_view()),
]
```

Question 2: how I need change method `get`

Comment: there is a mistake in your url path, change it to ```path('words/<int:id>', WordView.as_view()),```

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `urls.py` you should add your url like so ([adding a name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#examples) is useful to redirect from another view or from templates) :

```py
path('words/<int:id>/', WordView.as_view(), name='words'),
```

Now, to get your id in your `get` method you can retrieve it from the kwargs passed in the url like so :

```py
class WordView(View):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs['id']
        item = Word.objects.get(id=id)
        items_data = [{
            'id': item.id,
            'word': item.word,
            'transcription': item.transcription,
            'translation': item.translation,
            'example': item.example,
        }]

        return JsonResponse(items_data[0])
```